# Redirect google sheets to a function in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, upwork-api

I'm trying to redirect a **URL** to a **function in google-sheets** where this function should do some work later.

So as my understanding, i should create an **API** for this function using **Deploy as wep app** and then use this URL.

So what I've done is creating 2 script files `Api.gs` containing this code

```
function test() {
  Logger.log('Success!!')
}
```

and this should be the one I'll create an api for it.

the other file is `Authentication.gs` containing this code function

```
showSideBar() {
    var authorizationUrl = 'https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=The_Api_URL_generated_for_the_function_above&client_id=clientID&response_type=token';
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Press here to authroze</a>.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate().setTitle('Authroize');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page); 
}
```

This show a sidebar, when i press on the link it redirects me correctly but with an error, `Missing or invalid redirect_uri parameter value`.

> I'm trying to authenticate upwork and redirect it to google-sheets
> again
>
> So I was wondering what am doing is wrong? or if i'm doing is even possible ?

Comment: Could you clarify what your final result should be? Honestly I'd love to help you just based on your alias (half of my variables are named DOOM).

Comment: My final result should be a link in a sidebar (which the code above is doing) on clicking on this link it authorize my account on upwork and redirects me back to google spreadsheets to some sort of function or whatever in order to use the access token to access data inside upwork, if my clarification is not enough tell me please :D

Comment: If you want to run test from a sidebar all you need to do is call google.script.run.test() from within a js function or from some event

Comment: You could also run a function in one project from another project using [Appscript API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)

Comment: @Cooper , but you have canceled by this way the authentication I'm trying to make !! as you can see i'm trying to authenticate a user in upwork in the code above but i got problem with the redirect_uri. ( I want after pressing the authorization link and get authorized, got redirected to google sheets again or to a function that makes something in google sheets like printing hello or anything )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Enter this into the script editor and run showmysidebar() then click the button and see the toast appear in lower right corner.

```
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Success");
}

function showmysidebar() {
  var html='<input type="button" value="test" onclick="google.script.run.test();" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
}
```